# Using Jquery on jQuery generated ck te t

Tags: jquery

I have a relatively simple upload form where people can click on a button, so an extra upload field is being created in a different div:

```
$("#extraf").click(function(){
  $("#file2").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="files2" size="30" />');
});
```

But when people select their file, i want them to see what the name of the file is,
i looked trough several topics on StackOverflow and needed to use '.on()'. But it's still not working with the following code:

```
$("input:file").on("change", function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

or with

```
$("#files2").on("change", function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

I don't even get the alert, so i assume something is wrong, can somebody help me with this?

Thanks,
Regards,
Yannick

Comment: what is `ck te t` ??? also note that your code is going to create multiple elements with the same `id` - this is not valid - `id`s *must* be unique

Answer (score 1):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like this:

```
$("#file2").on("change","input[type=file]",function(){
     alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

<sub>[Using `:file` is deprecated.](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)</sub>

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKtGB/)

Comment: go ahead and try : `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file2" size="30" />
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#file2").on("change","input[type=file]",function(){
alert('');
     alert( $(this).val() );
}); 

 
  </script>
    
</html>`

Comment: @RoyiNamir Where is the `"file2"`(not `"files2"`) in your script?

Comment: @RoyiNamir See the demo in my answer! And pls define "what does not work"

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your scenario is invalid. See in the OP's question-> `$("#file2").append('<input type="file"`. So the inputs are added inside of the `"#file2"` element

Comment: Yeah I know,  The strange thing is that the basic example ( myne) doesnt work , while the more advanced ( op's question and your solution) Does work...